# Getting date and time of datetime (bug in MySQL?)

Tags: mysql

Running the following statement, MySQL seems to mix things up:

```
select now(), if(false, date(now()), time(now()));

| 2013-07-24 10:06:21 | 2010-06-21 00:00:00 |
```

If replacing the second argument of the `if` with a literal string, the statement behaves correctly:

```
select now(), if(false, 'Banana', time(now()));

| 2013-07-24 10:06:21 | 10:06:21 |
```

Is this a bug or some really strange quirk?

Comment: `SELECT '2013-07-24 10:06:21', IF(FALSE, DATE('2013-07-24 10:06:21'), TIME('2013-07-24 10:06:21'));` shows the same behavior (thus, now() isn't involved)

Comment: instead, `SELECT '2013-07-24 10:06:21', IF(TRUE, DATE('2013-07-24 10:06:21'), TIME('2013-07-24 10:06:21'));` works correctly as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `IF` has to be a datatype that includes the types of both arguments. So if one of the arguments is a `DATE` and the other is a `TIME`, the type of `IF` will be `DATETIME`.

This doesn't seem necessary in the trivial example query, but consider something like:

```
SELECT IF(col1, date(col2), time(col2)) AS dt
FROM Table
```

All the rows of the result have to have the same datatype in the `dt` column, even though the specific data will depend on what's in that row.

If you want just the date or time, convert it to a string.

Comment: Yes, you must be right. There needs to be a definite type for the column. So what is the best way to fix this? The thing I wanted to do was: `select if(created < date(now()), date(now()), time(now()))`, ie. show time if today, show date if yesterday or before.

Comment: I explained how to do it in the last line of my answer, do you need it spelled out?

Comment: No need for attitude. OK, so `if(true, cast(date(now()) as char), cast(time(now()) as char))`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I volunteer hours of my time every day giving free advice. If I get frustrated by the apparent incompetence of supposedly professional programmers, I think I have the right to show it occasionally.

Comment: It's a shame not everyone is as professional as you. Thanks for pointing out the problem.